# select rows from table and check if condition at column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I have to check certain rows from table and check `if-else` condition for each rows

TABLE: `report`

COLUMNS :
`sl.no`, `count`, `total_count`, `calls`

Sample Data:

```
sl.no       count       total_count calls
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           6           4
2           2           7           5
3           4           9           3
```

Here i have to check if condition

```
 if total_count > 6
 select 'Y
 else 
select 'N'
```

I get correct answer for single row. If there is multiple row it can't check all, it check only last row of my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**CASE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) expression

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN total_count > 6 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'N' END
FROM report
```

Comment: here it works . great. but i have to check another column in same table ie. count =2 then 'yes' else 'no' how can a case condition works here .

Comment: Same principle. Just use `CASE WHEN count = 2  THEN 'yes'...`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE`. You can read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN total_count > 6 THEN 'Y' ELSE ' N' END
FROM   Report
```

Comment: If he's using SQL Server 2012 or above, he could also use `SELECT *, IIF(total_count > 6, 'Y', 'N') FROM Reports`.

Comment: Just another method. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL version of ["inline if"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIf) is `CASE`:

```sql
SELECT 
    *,       
    CASE WHEN total_count > 6 THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END AS IsTotalCountGreaterThanSix
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use CASE.It work like if-else in t-SQL. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx)

For example:

```
SELECT [num],[count], [total_count], [calls], CASE WHEN [total_count] > 6 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END FROM t
```